# powershell Rename Script - Mostly functional, looking to finish and fully automate task

Tags: powershell, iteration, file-rename, batch-rename

This is my first post to Stack Overflow, and I avoided asking for help and tried to figure this out as much as I could on my own. I have very little scripting experience, but I'm looking to learn. I chose this project as a place to start, and felt like my goals for this script got out of hand rather quickly.

What I have is a functional, probably very bloated, script, that only does a fraction of what I wanted it to do for me.

***Here is the task I have, that before we were doing 100% by hand - manually file by file:***

***I have MP3 files of high importance that need to get copied off of an SD card and eventually moved to a shared drive that is backed up regularly.***

***These files are in the file name format of MMDDYYYYHHMMSS_RC-700R.mp3***

We store these files on our data share in its own directory, organized further by the month, leading me try to add that in as part of my script, but it is a less important feature.

My goal was to safely move these files off of the SD card, rename them - removing the TIME of the file, but if there were 2 (or more) files made on the same date to append an alphabetical iterative count up. I tried to comment out every step, not only for others to read, but to keep myself apprised of what I was trying to accomplish in each section of the code.

```
#Start by Clearing Host and Saving Transcript
Clear-Host
$date = Get-Date -Format 'dddd MM-dd-yyyy'
Start-Transcript -Path "F:\Script$date.txt" -NoClobber -Append

#Set locations - SD Card:Import
$Import = "C:\Users\Death\Desktop\Minutes"
$Source = "F:\Minutes\"
$Destination = "F:\Final\"

#Test if $Source Exists, if not Create directory for Files to be transferred to
if(!(Test-Path -Path $Source))  {  
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Source
    Write-Host "Folder path has been created successfully at: " $Source    
    }
   else { 
   Write-Host "The given folder path $Source already exists"; 
   }
   #Test if $Destination exists and create if false
   if(!(Test-Path -Path $Destination))  {  
     New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Destination
     Write-Host "Folder path has been created successfully at: $Destination "}
    else { 
    Write-Host "The given folder path $Destination already exists"; 
    }

   #Copy Items from $Import location
   Get-ChildItem -Path $Import -Filter *.mp3 | Copy-Item -Destination $Source
   #Rename Files adding Dashes between MM DD YYYY and HHMMSS
   Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Filter *.mp3 | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -Replace ('^\n*(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{6}).(?:...)(\d{3})\w','TC $1-$2-$3-$4')}
   
   #Move files into $Destination\Year\Month created - Need to add


#Move files into $NewPath\Year\Month created
#Running in to problems with moving the files after they have been renamed - Likely due to 

Get-ChildItem -File -Path $Source -Filter '*.mp3' |
ForEach-Object {

    $Year = $_.LastWriteTime.Year
    $Month = $_.LastWriteTime.Month
    $Monthname = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName($Month)
    $ArchDir = "$Destination\$Year\$Monthname\"

    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $ArchDir)) { New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path $ArchDir | Out-Null }
    Move-Item -Path $Source\*.mp3 -Destination $ArchDir -Verbose
    }


#Would like to add a list of files renamed and where they moved to instead of just Enter to exit
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

I have had little parts of my goals working in other versions of this code, but this is my most functional one.

Problems that currently exist:

1. I haven't figured out how to safely iterate files created on the same day when renaming files and leaving off the TIME - So as it is currently functioning I have it leaving the TIME on the file and I am manually removing it and adding any letters when needed
2. It is throwing all of the files in to $Destination in the Month of the first file, and putting all the files in there (not a huge issue as this was extra)

I would like it to list every move operation as well as any errors. It is doing this now with the $Source & $Destination folders & the -Verbose on the final GCI - Move operation.

Until I demonstrate that the script is 100% functional I have all locations in the script on my local machine to keep my boss happy.

*I am sorry for the wall of text & Thanks in advance for any assistance.*

Answer (score 2):

This looks way over-complicated.

For the file parts, it could be as simple as this...
As per your stated use case:

> 1. My goal was to safely move these files off of the SD card,
> 2. rename them - removing the TIME of the file,

```
Clear-Host
$SourcePath = 'C:\Temp'
$TargetPath = 'C:\Temp\TempChild'

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -Filter '*.mp3' | 
ForEach {
    $FileName = $PSItem
    Try
    {
        If ((Get-Item -Path "$TargetPath\$($FileName.Name)" -ErrorAction Stop))
        {
            Rename-Item -Path "$TargetPath\$($PSItem.Name)" -NewName "$($FileName.Name -replace '\d+_')" -WhatIf
            Move-Item -Path $FileName.FullName -Destination $TargetPath -WhatIf
        }
    }
    Catch {Move-Item -Path $FileName.FullName -Destination $TargetPath -WhatIf}
}

# Results
<#
# When the file does not exists
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\04122021143000_RC-M1234R.mp3 Destination: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M1234R.mp3".

# When the file exists
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M1234R.mp3 Destination: C:\Temp\TempChild\RC-M1234R.mp3".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\04122021143000_RC-M1234R.mp3 Destination: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M1234R.mp3".
#>
```

You can create new paths, without using New-Item. Just use the -Force switch/parameter on the copy/move action.

```
Test-Path -Path "$TargetPath\test1" 
# Results
<#
False
#>

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -Filter '*.mp3' | 
Copy-Item -Destination "$TargetPath\test1" -Force -WhatIf
# Results
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\04122021143000_RC-M1234R.mp3 Destination: C:\Temp\TempChild\test1".
#>

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -Filter '*.mp3' | 
Copy-Item -Destination "$TargetPath\test1" -Force 
Test-Path -Path "$TargetPath\test1" 
Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetPath -Filter '*.mp3'
# Results
<#
True
    Directory: C:\Temp\TempChild


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----          4/8/2021   6:04 PM             39 04122021143000_RC-M12345R.mp3
-a----          4/8/2021   6:04 PM             39 04122021143000_RC-M1234R.mp3
#>
```

As for

> 3. but if there were 2 (or more) files made on the same date to append an alphabetical iterative count up.

I am not sure why you use alpha vs numeric.  Since alpha would limit you to 26 letters before you'd end up having to double that string. Numeric of course, you can just look at the number and increment by 1.

Here's what I mean, just using your file name vs file properties. Yet, you can do the same approach, by looking at the file properties in the mix.

```
Clear-Host
$SourcePath = 'C:\Temp'
$TargetPath = 'C:\Temp\TempChild'

Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -Filter '*.mp3' | 
ForEach {
    $FileName = $PSItem

    Try
    {
        If (
            -Not ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetPath -Filter $FileName.Name) -match "(?<=RC-M\d+R\d)") -and 
            ($FileName.Name -replace '_\.*') -match 
            ((Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetPath -Filter $FileName.Name)  -replace '_\.*')
        )
        {
            Rename-Item -Path "$TargetPath\$($FileName.Name)" -NewName "$(
                                                                            $FileName.Name -replace 'R\.', 'R1.'
                                                                         )" -ErrorAction Stop -WhatIf

            Move-Item -Path $FileName.FullName -Destination $TargetPath -Verbose -WhatIf
        }
    }
    Catch
    {
        $FileToIncrement = (
                                Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetPath | 
                                Where-Object -Property Name -Match ($FileName.BaseName -replace 'R\d+')
                           ).FullName 

        if($FileToIncrement -match "(?<=RC-M\d+R)(?<bv>\d+)")
        {
            Rename-Item -Path $FileToIncrement -NewName (
                                                            $FileToIncrement -replace "(?<=RC-M\d+R)(\d+)", 
                                                            ("{0:0000}" -f (([int]::Parse($matches.bv)+1)))
                                                        ) -Verbose -WhatIf

            Move-Item -Path $FileName.FullName -Destination $TargetPath -Verbose -WhatIf
        }
    }
}

# Results - when incrementer does not exist for the matched time string
<#
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M12345R.mp3 Destination: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M12345R1.mp3".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\04122021143000_RC-M12345R.mp3 Destination: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M12345R.mp3".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M1234R.mp3 Destination: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M1234R1.mp3".
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\04122021143000_RC-M1234R.mp3 Destination: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M1234R.mp3".
#>

# Results - when incrementer exists for the matched time string
<#
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M12345R1.mp3 Destination: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M12345R0002.mp3".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\04122021143000_RC-M12345R.mp3 Destination: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M12345R.mp3".
What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M1234R1.mp3 Destination: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M1234R0002.mp3".
What if: Performing the operation "Move File" on target "Item: C:\Temp\04122021143000_RC-M1234R.mp3 Destination: C:\Temp\TempChild\04122021143000_RC-M1234R.mp3".
#>
```

Comment: __Thanks__, I truly do appreciate the pointers.. 

In my code (as overcomplicated as it is) I had it partially working doing what I wanted. I just had to manually do the final steps.

I want the output to be named "" TC MM-DD-YYYY($i).mp3 ""    

--Most often there is one file per day. There will **never** be over 26  

`
('^\n*(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{6}).(?:...)(\d{3})\w','TC $1-$2-$3-$4')    
`

With my posted code I still manually have to delete the HHMMSS & Check for duplicate dates while doing so.